# Asserting two List<List<T>> Are Equivalent to Each Other

Tags: c#, nunit

To make sure that two lists are the same, in nunit, we can use [`CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent`](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionAssert&r=2.4.1) to check that these two lists contain the same elements ( orders not important).

But how to check whether two `List<List<T>>` are equivalent? The idea is that if one `List<T>` has the same elements as the other `List<T>` ( again, order not important) then they are equal.

Comment: These all seem to be decent answers.  I guess one thing I would ask is, if this is being done for unit testing only, is speed ultimately a concern?  Of course, it would be nice, but is the return on the investment of time worth it over having a solution that you know works correctly?  Certainly, it may be, but I've learned with experience that some problems aren't as necessary to solve as others.

Comment: @Wonko, as decent as they look, ultimately I want to cut down the probability of bugs inside my unit tests ( I don't want to write unit tests to test my unit tests to test my unit tests, AKA unit testing Inception). So, I want clear, succinct, impossible-to-go-wrong syntax that does this

Comment: absolutely, I agree.  That's why I would be more inclined to do a brute force, "I know it works" solution (with a few "safe" shortcuts that you are comfortable work), rather than trying to squeeze out efficiency.

Answer (score 5):

You do have to loop through them to be sure that they are equivalent, but with some important shortcuts:

1. If they are actually the same instance (and in real code this often comes up), then `ReferenceEquals(x, y)` will return true. Otherwise it won't. If `ReferenceEquals` returns true, then they are equivalent.
2. If one is null and the other isn't, then obviously they aren't equal (if they are both null you'll have caught that above with `ReferenceEquals`). You'll need to test for null anyway for safety, so you've another short-cut in many cases.
3. If they are of different sizes then (for most definitions of equivalence, there are exceptions) they are not equal. Return false immediately.
4. The moment you've found a mismatch, you can return false without continuing to check.
5. It will be faster to compare them if they are already sorted. If you can keep them sorted, or failing that keep track of whether they are sorted or not and then sort only when needed, you can massively speed things up. (Note though that many sorting algorithms have their worse-case behaviour when needlessly sorting a list that is already sorted).

Comment: That's tantamount to doing a brute force compare for all the elements, isn't it?

Comment: @Ngu: Yes, and there is no other way.

Comment: Yes, but the short-cuts are important (ReferenceEquals especially)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an attempt, not tested. If each inner list contains `m` elements, and the outer list-list contains `n` lists, I believe the complexity is `O (n^2 x m)`, but I might be wrong.
Assumptions:

1. `T` does not implement `IComparable` or any such interface that allows sorting.
2. Ordering is irrelevant to equality for both the `List<List<T>>`s and the composing `List<T>` objects.

--

```
public static bool ListListsAreEqual<T>(List<List<T>> listlist1, List<List<T>> listlist2)
{
    if (listlist1.Count != listlist2.Count)
        return false;

    var listList2Clone = listlist2.ToList();

    foreach (var list1 in listlist1)
    {
        var indexOfMatchInList2 = listList2Clone
                   .FindIndex(list2 => ListsArePermutations(list1, list2));

        if (indexOfMatchInList2 == -1)
            return false;

        listList2Clone.RemoveAt(indexOfMatchInList2);
    }

    return true;
}

private static bool ListsArePermutations<T>(List<T> list1, List<T> list2)
{
    return list1.Count == list2.Count && new HashSet<T>(list1).SetEquals(list2);
}
```

Comment: Why not sort the lists and do a straight compare?

Comment: @ Daniel: How do you know they implement IComparable? IEquatable is possibly all we can assume.

Comment: The type `T` doesn't have to support `IComparable`. `List<T>.Sort` can take a delegate that defines the comparison.

Comment: @Daniel: And how do we write a Comparison<T> delegate that works for all T?

Comment: Hm. On the sorting thing, you could require a comparison delegate to be passed in for things that don't implement `IComparable`. Might be a reasonable trade off for not having to implement code like this yourself all the time.

Comment: Also, wouldn't the `ListsArePermutations` be incorrect if one list contained `[1,2,2,3]` and another contained `[1,1,2,3]`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you get around checking for each element individually.
I'll typically first check for equal length, then loop for say i over the lists' length and check that list1[i]==list2[i]

**update**

Sorry, missed the (central) part about elements not having to be in order. In that case, create a HashSet with the elements of the second list and check for each element in list1 if it's in the hashset. This reduces the running time for the lookup from linear to logarithmic.

**update 2**
As noted by Donald Ray, you have to check both ways if you have possible multiple occurrences of single objects in any of the lists.

Comment: I think you are missing this part: **The idea is that if one `List<T>` has the same elements as the other `List<T>` ( again, order not important) then they are equal.** Note that two lists are the same if all the elements are the same, regardless of order.

Comment: @Ngu Soon Hui, true order isn't important to you, but unless you need to keep them in their starting order, and if there's a chance you'll need to compare them more than once, then keeping them sorted will enable a faster comparison. It **may** not be appropriate in your case, but if it is appropriate, the gain can be considerable.

Comment: @Jon, the thing is that I would have a difficulty in defining the elements order. In other words I don't know how to implement  `IComparer<T>` for that particular `T`.

Comment: yea sorry missed the most important part somehow. pls chk update

Comment: Concerning your update, HashSet has constant lookup complexity, not logarithmic.

Comment: @Matajon, 1st thanks for mentioning HashSet, HashTable was clearly superfluous. 2nd: Um... care to elaborate about constant lookup complexity? 3rd: Only makes my argument stronger in any case, right?

Comment: What if there is an element in the second list not in the first? You also have to create a hashset of the first list  and check if each element of list 2 is in it.

Comment: @DonaldRay, no: if the lists are of equal length and each element from list 1 is in list 2 there no "space" in list 2 for superfluous elements. Ie one of the elements in list 1 must be missing, so you'd find out about that, too.

Comment: @DonaldRay oh. you're right for multiple occurences of the same object. which wasn't excluded in the original question. so yea, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to write your own code to do this.

Look at how CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent works with Reflector then write your own helper class "MyAsserts".

You will have to be clever if you wish to run faster than O(n^2*m^2) where *n* is the number of lists in the outmost list and *m* is the number of items in the inner lists.

The simple solution is to loop over all “inner lists” in the list1 and use the code from CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent to check if list2 contains such a list.  Then swap list1 and list2 and repeat.   However you can do a lot better.

(You then need to work out how to produce a helpful message when the lists are not equivalent.)

Answer (score -1):

I'd use `SelectMany()` and flatten the list. Now you can either compare element against element, using Assert.Equals() or use a normal collection assert for lists. A query expression with two from clauses will do the same thing:

```
void AssertEquals<T>(List<List<T>> expected, List<List<T>> actual)
{
  var flatExpected = expected.SelectMany(x=>x);
  var flatActual = expected.SelectMany(x=>x);

  CollectionAssert.Equals(flatExpected, flatActual);
}
```

Note that this is a very naive implementation only, the flattened sequences may be equal while the source sequences contain the same elements but in a different partitioning.

Comment: -1 the first list is [{1,2},{3,4}], and the 2nd is [{1,3},{2,4}]. If you use selectMany you will find that they are the same, but in fact they are not.

Comment: aehm, no?! [{1,2,3},{4}], [{1,2},{3,4}] will be the same but not the example you have given.

Comment: `CollectionAssert.Equals() == Object.Equals()`